# Medion P4501 freeze on brand image

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, usb-debugging

I have a Medion P4501 phone. After the battery died, i start charging but it frooze on the Medion-brand. I was looking for a long time how to solve it but nothing worked.

The problem is:

- the power button + volume up/down doesn't work: after more than 20 times, turns up only the Medion brand
- Fastboot (power button + volume up and down) gives an error: 
  'failed to open file/mmcl/p4501.v1/CONF/P4501.xml with error no -1'
- Usb debugging is turned off i believe. When i plugged in the phone, i couldn't find it in the microsoft divice manager.
- Adb didnt work because it didn't find my phone
- the phone isn't rooted

I hope someone can help me with this. I cracking my brains on it for a few weeks.

Comment: The only solution here is flashing the phone. Did you try flashing it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Flashing a stock firmware should solve your problem.

Firmware download links from [here](https://www.medion.com/gb/service/start/_search.php?groupID=3&groupName=Tablet). 
Additional instructions, guide from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2615087)

Comment: I never tried flashing it because i can't put the phone in download mode. Or it this not nessecary?